# Whats the best way to fetch multiple Models from server before App is initialized?

Tags: ajax, spine.js

i have 3 models i need to successfully fetch the data from the server before I init my app

```
ModelA.fetch()
ModelB.fetch()
ModelC.fetch()
```

would i use `$.Deferred()` for this or is there a better option in spine.js?

Answer (score 2):

i ended up with this implementation:

create a deferred for each model

```
@modela = new $.Deferred()
@modelb = new $.Deferred()
@modelc = new $.Deferred()
```

then bind events when the model is done fetching

```
ModelA.bind 'refresh', => @modela.resolve()
ModelB.bind 'refresh', => @modelb.resolve()
ModelC.bind 'refresh', => @modelc.resolve()
```

and finally resolve the promise when all are done

```
$.when(
  @modela, @modelb, @modelc
).then(
  @appReady,
  @appError
)
```

appReady gets called when all models are successfully fetched.